# What is best practice for the amount of entity bundles, related to performance

Tags: performance, entities

My site uses [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) entities

In my use case it is easier to work with many bundles under one entity type instead of multiple entity types 
(because in Panels, Views, Flags, separate entity types require separate instances, data of one entity type is relatively isolated to another entity type, thats why I don't use multiple entity types)

I want to be sure that this does not impact the site performance.
The site currently uses one entity type with approx. 30 entity bundles.
I also do not use the built in taxonomy system, but use entity bundles instead.

I don't use custom entity type properties, apart from the standard ones (title, author, created, etc.)

Is it advisable, from a performance standpoint, to start using more entity types?